# Why are my entities disapearing after deploy?

Tags: entity-framework, windows-server-2003, wcf-data-services

I created an OData service for a couple of our entities, and on my developer machine (WinXP), everything works like it should, this is what I get when accessing the service:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://localhost:2332/ContactOData.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="Client">
      <atom:title>Client</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="Vehicle">
      <atom:title>Vehicle</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="Contact">
      <atom:title>Contact</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

Now after I deployed that service to a testserver (Win2K3), all my entities are gone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://dev-cont2011b/ContactOData/ContactOData.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

There are no error messages, nothing in the event log. My connections string is ok (I tested this with a simple `test.aspx` page which fetches something out of the database and shows it on the page ==> this works).

When I manually enter the url for one of the entities (Client), this is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?> 
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> 
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="nl-BE">Resource not found for the segment 'Client'.</message> 
</error>
```

The .NET Framework 3.5 is installed on that server. I ran all the updates.

I've been banging my head on this one for the last couple of hours. I don't know what else I can do or test.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have seperate debug and release configs? You may be deploying with a different config than you are using to test locally.

Comment: @Chad: I deployed the same site on my own IIS (as I normally develop on the Casini server), and there it also works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install this update:

> **[ADO.NET Data Services Update for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 for Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=21f20103-551e-4501-89b3-e53fcac5cffd)**

Apparently, this one isn't included into windows update by default. You have to run it manually.

This was needed because I changed the default `InitializeService` method so it takes a `DataServiceConfiguration` in stead of an `IDataServiceConfiguration`:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 20);
}
```

This is needed if you want to enable server side paging (`SetEntitySetPageSize`) (amongst others).

Answer (score 0):

New try:

It is a RESX problem

```
<message xml:lang="nl-BE">Resource not found for the segment 'Client'.</message>
```

It is trying to lookup the nl-BE translation for the name Client.

Comment: Ok, what can I try then to confirm this? And even better... to solve this?

Comment: check for a nl-BE.resx file in your project does it have an entry for client, if not add it. If no file add the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in this case, "Client" is not a resource (resx), it is one of my entities, and no I don't have any resources (resx). This is a clean project I work on. Just added a entity framework model, dragged some tables from my database onto the model, and added an ADO.NET data service. Nothing more, nothing less.